# How to store multiple datas in a single file using python?

Tags: python, operating-system

```
def appendnew():
        file = open("emailpasswd.txt",'w')
        email = add
        password = pas
        file.write(email)
        file.write(password)
        file.close()
```

I am working on a project called password manager in python for that i need to save passwords and emails in a file , but when i use the above code every time i input a new password and email python overwrites the existing data , also i need to get passwords when i type in the corresponding email also vice versa,How can i do it?

Comment: opening a file with 'w' will overwrites existing data, you can use ‘a’ instead, which is used to add new data to the end of the file

Comment: @RezaRahemtola How to get password when i type the corresponding email

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `'w'` as the mode to `open()`, it tells the OS that the file should be overwritten if a file with that name already exists. To append to it instead, you can use the `'a'` mode. You can find a list of modes in the documentation for [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

To get the password belonging to an email address, you need to change the file structure somewhat. Replace your writes with `file.write(f"{email}\0{password}\n")`, then iterate the lines  with `file.readlines()` and look for one that  `.startswith(f"{email}\0")`, then use `line.split('\0', 1)[1]` to get the password.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to write to file without losing the content of the file we need to open the file with append mode.

The `open()` function have following paramter:

`open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`

2nd paramater is used to define the mode of file with which file is open, if we want to open a file in append mode we have to do `open('filename, 'a')` a for append

you can open a file as:

`file = open("emailpasswd.txt",'a') # second paramter a for append mode`

and do your stuff like:

`file.write(email) # writing content in file`

and, after your work you can close it with

`file.close() # close file, as you do not want to occupy resource when do not need them any longer`

Python is able to do that resource managing stuff like closing file within itself, if you want to handle closing like stuff for python itself you can use

`with open('emailpasswd.txt', 'a') as f:`

and proceed as the below code.

```
def appendnew():
    with open('emailpasswd.txt', 'a') as f:
        email = 'email'
        password = 'pass'
        f.write(email)
        f.write(password)

appendnew()
```

Comment: How can i get password when i type the corresponding email

Comment: you can use the file read mode to read the content of the file and store file data in a variable and then use variable wherever you need to do your stuff.